# Finite sequences of prime numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, big-list

There is a lot of [*prime sequences*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_prime_numbers): prime numbers in a special form.
For example *Mersenne primes* are primes of the the form $2^n-1$, or *Pythagorean prime* are primes of the form $4n+1$.

*Even primes* are primes of the form $2n$. The only even prime is $2$. Is that anything else? I mean primes sequences which are finite sequences by proof, and not by conjecture.

Comment: All primes less than 1, all primes less than 2, all primes less than 3, ...

Comment: I am not sure your definition of Gaussian prime is correct...

Comment: Also I don't really understand your question. Surely ANY finite list of primes is such an example "by proof".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An integer-matrix quadratic form represents all prime numbers if and only if it represents the primes $2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 67, 73$.

Exposition: https://math.nd.edu/assets/20630/hahntoulouse.pdf. (See page 674.)

Answer (score 2):

- $5$ is the only prime that has $5$ as the right-most digit.
- $(2,3)$ is the only pair whose difference is $1$.
- There are only two sets $(a,b,c,d)=(2,3,5,7),(3,2,5,13)$ such that 
  $$a+b=c\ \ \text{and}\ \ ac=b+d$$
  where $a,b,c,d$ are all primes.

Answer (score 1):

The only prime that can be written in the form $n^2-1$ is $3$.

Comment: For every prime $p$ there exists $k$ such that $p$ is the only prime of the form $n^2 - k$.

Comment: @Yoni R: That's a nice result.  As I look at it, I'm thinking that the $k$ should be a perfect square.  Is that right?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure what I said is true for $p=2$. But for an odd prime, I know a solution which fixes a certain perfect square $k$ (a direct generalization of $n^2 - 1 = 3$). If you fix $k$ to be a perfect square then there is *at most* one prime value. If you fix $k$ to be an integer that isn't a square and ask how many prime values there are, then this seems like a very hard question.

Answer (score 0):

Since the other answers are base-dependent too, try *[truncatable primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncatable_prime)* which are primes which, when written in base 10, remains prime when you successively delete one digit from the end (or beginning) of the digit "word"/string.

Answer (score 0):

3 is the the only prime where the sum of all the digits is 3.

Since we can show that if the digits sum to 3 its a multiple of 3 and the only multiple of 3 that is prime is 3 itself.

2 is the prime that has a even right most digit

Answer (score 0):

The [prime-generating polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime-GeneratingPolynomial.html) $n^2 + n + 41$ is prime for $n=0, \ldots, 39$.

Comment: But are those the only primes, or are there an infinite number?

Comment: And it is also prime for $n=42,43,45,46,47,48,50,51,52,53,54,55,57,58,\dots$. [A056561](http://oeis.org/A056561)

Comment: Mark, it is currently unknown whether $n^2 + 1$ is infinitely often prime. I would guess than $n^2 + n + 41$ is no easier.

Comment: However, even if nothing is "known", it would be a huge surprise if $n^2+n+41$ (or $n^2+1$) was prime for only finitely many $n$.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes it would be, and that was the motivation of the question. A lot of question about prime numbers lead us to the answer that there are inifinitly many solution or we don't know the answer at all how many solution could be to the given problem. I'm really waiting for a surprising answer.